# How to Show detail section only with out any space in Active Report

Tags: c#-4.0, activereports

i have a active report without any Page Header , Report Header and no any Footer type section.
for more detail see attached image.

[image]
**Now issue is that When we run this report we got space before report detail.**
for more detail see attached image
[image]
Below is my code

```
 Assembly asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(this.GetType());
                    System.IO.Stream stre = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(asm.GetName().Name + ".CoverPage.rpx");
                    using (XmlTextReader xr = new XmlTextReader(stre))
                    {
                        arCoverPage.LoadLayout(xr);
                    }  
                    //Get detail for Cover Page
                   AddingReportSection(report, HeaderType.CoverPage);
                    arCoverPage.DataSource = lstCoverPage;
                    arCoverPage.Run();
```

**I want remove this space.so please give me any suggestion/idea**

I also tried to set height of page but i am  not get sucess.

```
arCoverPage.PageSettings.DefaultPaperSize = false;
arCoverPage.PageSettings.Gutter = 3.0F;
arCoverPage.PageSettings.Orientation = DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Document.PageOrientation.Portrait;
arCoverPage.PageSettings.PaperHeight = 5.0F;    
this.viReport.Document = arCoverPage.Document;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the top margin to 0, for example:

```
arCoverPage.PageSettings.Margins.Top = 0f;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the white space from the page, please set the Margins for the page to zero. This can either be done at design time using the [PageSettingsDialog](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/ActiveReports6/topic130.html) or at runtime by accessing the [PageSettings](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/ActiveReports6/topic4220.html/GrapeCity.ActiveReports.v7~GrapeCity.ActiveReports.PageSettings.html) class like you are already doing. However make sure that you also set the Margins.